# Why does the html5 SpeechRecognition API not work when I'm connected to a VPN?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech-recognition-api

I was making an app to use for my job with the HTML5 SpeechRecognition API (Chrome) and it works great until I connect to a VPN. Surely it's not sending this speech data to a remote source. All my code is served locally. I use a local server so the ES6 import feature will work. Why can't I use the API when connected to the company VPN?

Answer (score 2):

The *SpeechRecognition* engine is not embedded in your chrome browser. There is a server behind it.

When you use the API, your browser sends data to a server, and retrieve the transcription from it.

Check if your VPN is blocking the connection with the *SpeechRecognition* server.

Comment: So it sends the voice data to a remote server? Or a local server on my pc?

Comment: To a Remote server.

Comment: You should inspect your local network, find the IP/PORT and ask your network admin to allow you to access.

Comment: Wow. That's wild, can't believe they wouldnt involve a remote server in a web standard. How do we know our data is secure? Who controls this server? How is it even funded? So sketchy. I didnt even imagine that could be the case.

Comment: I have already worked for a company with a SpeechReconizer engine. It takes too much memory to embed it, so make it using the cloud is the best solution. And yes, there are security problems. A LOT OF PROBLEMS!

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition), speech data is sent to a server-based service.

> On Chrome, using Speech Recognition on a web page involves a
>   server-based recognition engine. Your audio is sent to a web service
>   for recognition processing, so it won't work offline.

Edit: Verified this with [Google Chrome's privacy whitepaper](https://www.google.ca/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html#speech).